# Get Year, Month, and Date from Variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a `variable` of the format `$var_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.txt`

```
Eg: variable=sample_data_2017_01_01_10_22_10.txt
```

I need to extract the following from this variable:

```
Year=YYYY
Month=MM
Date=DD
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the native `bash`, regex operator `~` and use the captured groups to store them in variables for using it later.

```
variable="sample_data_2017_01_01_10_22_10.txt"

if [[ $variable =~ ^sample_data_([[:digit:]]{4})_([[:digit:]]{2})_([[:digit:]]{2}).*$ ]]; then
    year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    month="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    date="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

Comment: Very nice solution sir.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Year=$(echo $variable | cut -d '_' -f3)
Month=$(echo $variable | cut -d '_' -f4)
Date=$(echo $variable | cut -d '_' -f5)
```

This only works if you are sure your variable is laid out in the exact way you describe in your question though. It splits up the string delimited by the '_' character and then returns the field denoted `-f` argument to cut.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `read` command with setting `IFS='_'`.

```
$ variable=sample_data_2017_01_01_10_22_10.txt
$ IFS='_' read -r tmp tmp Year Month Date tmp <<< "$variable"
$ echo "$Year : $Month : $Date"
2017 : 01 : 01
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
Year=$(echo $variable | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[3]}')
Month=$(echo $variable | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[4]}')
Day=$(echo $variable | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[5]}')
```

Comment: You don't need multiple `split()` calls, just do it once, and print the first 3 elements as they will be spliced to the array `a` upon first split itself

Comment: something as `read -r year month day < <(awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[3],a[4],a[5]}' <<<"$variable")`

Answer (score 0):

Building on some of the other awk solutions a more complete solution would be:

```
echo $variable | awk -F_ '{ printf "Year="$3"\nMonth="$4"\nDate="$5"\n" }'
```